# Ambigously defined column in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've the following subquery in an sql query:

```
(
 SELECT ID_PLAN, ID_CURSO, NEDICION, NOMBRE AS NOMBREUNIDAD FROM ASISTEN, ALUMNOS, UNIDADES
     WHERE ASISTEN.COD = ALUMNOS.COD AND UNIDADES.IDESTRUCTURA = ALUMNOS.IDESTRUCTURA
     AND UNIDADES.CDUNDORG = ALUMNOS.CDUNDORG
     AND UPPER(TRANSLATE(UNIDADES.NOMBRE, 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU')) LIKE '%CONSEJERIA%'
     GROUP BY ID_PLAN, ID_CURSO, NEDICION) ASIS
```

Problem I have I believe lies in that both table ALUMNOS and UNIDADES have a column named 'NOMBRE' so if I attempt to execute the query I obtain:

918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

To avoid that I thought about changing NOMBRE AS NOMBREUNIDAD to:

```
 UNIDADES.NOMBRE AS NOMBREUNIDAD
```

But if I do that I get a:

979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

So, I don't know what to do so that subquery executes properly.

What should I change to properly execute query without changing the column name?

Comment: since you have no SUM/COUNT  it makes no sense to have a GROUP BY

Comment: Please ask about 1 case of code that does what you don't expect at a time. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]. Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. PS Your errors are faqs.

Answer (score -1):

Aliases are pretty useful, if you use them. The simplify queries and make them easier to read and maintain. I'd suggest you to do so, as it'll also help query to work because Oracle doesn't know which table you actually meant when you selected those 4 columns - which tables do they belong to?

This is just a guess as I don't know your tables so you'll have to fix it yourself. Also, I literally `JOIN`ed tables; try to avoid comma-separating them in `FROM` clause and doing join in `WHERE` clause as it is supposed to *filter* data.

`GROUP BY`, as already commented, is probably useless. If you wanted to fetch *distinct* set of values, then use appropriate keyword: `distinct`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id_plan,
                s.id_curso,
                u.nedicion,
                u.nombre
  FROM asisten n
       JOIN alumnos s ON n.cod = s.cod
       JOIN unidades u
          ON     u.idestructura = s.idestructura
             AND u.cdundorg = s.cdundorg
 WHERE UPPER (TRANSLATE (u.nombre, 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU')) LIKE '%CONSEJERIA%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve my problem:

```
(
 SELECT ID_PLAN, ID_CURSO, NEDICION, UNIDADES.NOMBRE AS NOMBREUNIDAD
 FROM ASISTEN, ALUMNOS, UNIDADES
 WHERE ASISTEN.COD = ALUMNOS.COD AND UNIDADES.IDESTRUCTURA = ALUMNOS.IDESTRUCTURA
 AND UNIDADES.CDUNDORG = ALUMNOS.CDUNDORG
 AND UPPER(TRANSLATE(UNIDADES.NOMBRE, 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU')) LIKE '%CONSEJERIA%'
 GROUP BY UNIDADES.NOMBRE,ID_PLAN, ID_CURSO, NEDICION
 )
```